# Deutsche Bahn Delay Passenger Compensation & Business Travel

Tags: trains, compensation, business-travel, deutsche-bahn

In the case of a delay while traveling by train in the EU, one is [entitled to a compensation in the event of a delayed arrival of 25% of the price paid for a single ticket for delays of more than 60 minutes and 50% when the delay is more than 120 minutes](https://int.bahn.de/en/booking-information/passenger-rights/legal-regulations). In the case of business travel where the train ticket is paid for by the employer and not the employee, who is eligible to collect & keep this compensation? The employer or the employee? (Barring any employer-employee agreements to the contrary.)

In the case of compensation paid out under EU Regulation 261/2004 for delayed air travel, [it seems that it is quite clear that the passenger (i.e. the employee) is eligible for compensation](https://www.claimcompass.eu/blog/en/business-trip-flight-compensation/) and that the regulation does not define compensation rights for the ticket purchaser (i.e. employer). Does similar clarity exist in the regulations for passenger rights for rail travelers?

Comment: I think it is mostly a legal thing and not much related to travel (so similar to all things your employer may give to you). Is ti compensating your time? But so you cannot account twice (so to your employer). Is it compensating for extra snacks? (which you will not bill to your company: ok). It is complex. Ask your employer.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I applied for compensation it was refunded to my Euro account, not to the original form or payment (which was a credit card).

The claim must be filed either online using the account from which the ticket was booked (easy) or by physical mail using a paper form and all relevant receipts (cumbersome). It's certainly  a lot easier if you have access to the booking account.

> (Barring any employer-employee agreements to the contrary.)

Quite likely you can not exclude this from the discussion and that's probably the deciding factor. Most companies have policies around that sort of thing (frequent flyer benefits, loyalty benefits, etc) and I think that would fall under this basic category as well. You can just ask your employer or look up the policy yourself. Most companies I worked for give those benefits to the employee anyway, so I wouldn't deep dive into the legality of it until you really need to.

Comment: "most companies give those benefits to the employee" - don't forget to pay taxes for them. They are "geldwerte Vorteile" that count towards your income. Although there was a recent exclusion specifically for bonus points from DB.

Comment: @asdfex: Interesting. In the US frequent flyer miles earned through travel are definitely not taxable. https://smithpatrickcpa.com/are-your-frequent-flyer-miles-taxed-when-redeemed/ That's mainly due to the impossibility of valuing them : given the craziness of airline pricing including dynamic pricing of mile earning and redemption, the cash value of point fluctuates massively. I would have no clue on how to turn my mileage earnings into a taxable number.